# pygame isn't working on my version of python how do fix pygame installation error?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to import pygame but python isn't reading it properly and saying a earlier version needs to be installed but I'm using python 3.5.3 so it should be working.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`
in the control center and it says

> (Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done python-pygame is already the newest version
>   (1.9.3+dfsg-2). You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to
>   correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 1.4.8) but 1.4.9 is to be installed E:
>   Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages
>   (or specify a solution).

and it is not working.

```
#!usr/bin/env python
# Basic 2d building game, Builder
import pygame
import random
import shutil
import time
import math
import sys
import os


debug_game_data = int(sys.argv[1])
current_version = "0.5.0"

WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 700

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Builder {}".format(current_version))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace.ttf", 13)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/minecraft.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/pygame.py", line 4, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'
```

I expect the pygame installation to work so I can work on coding.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'

You have this problem because you use name `pygame.py` for your script. And now `import pygame` loads your script instead of expected module. And it can't find `pygame.init()` in your script.

Rename your script for something different - ie. `script.py` - and it resolves your problem. And you don't need to install it again.

---

If you have problem with installing `PyGame` then use `pip` to install it.

```
pip install pygame
```

or

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

I have Linux Mint with Python 3.7 and PyGame 1.9.6 - the newest PyGame's version.
With `apt` you can't get the newest version.